# NSCollectionView, left align with Compositional Layout

Tags: macos, nscollectionview

I've been trying to implement a left aligned list of tokens, (NSTextField inside a box NSBox).

This is what I want to get:

[image]

I am using a NSCollectionView with Compositional Layout configured with :

- ITEM, with estimated width (initial value = 80) and fixed height (16)
- GROUP, with fractional width (1.0, ice full width) and fixed height (16)
  Items will be placed inside sections ("Genre" and "Combined Artists" in example above)

The idea is that when the items get their actual field contents, autolayout constraints will automatically calculate the box width and place the items one after the other, wrapping to a new line for more items.

This never happens when the data snapshot is applied.

Instead what I get is this:

[image]

The interesting thing is that when I resize the enclosing window, the desired layout is achieved!!!

It looks like the first time the collection view is rendered using the estimated size.

Sample Code:

```
////

- (void)configureLayout
{
    float iWW = 80;
    float iHH = 16;
    
    ////////////////////
    // Item Definition
    
    NSCollectionLayoutSize *itemSize = [NSCollectionLayoutSize sizeWithWidthDimension:[NSCollectionLayoutDimension estimatedDimension:iWW]
                                                                      heightDimension:[NSCollectionLayoutDimension absoluteDimension:iHH]];
    NSCollectionLayoutItem *item = [NSCollectionLayoutItem itemWithLayoutSize:itemSize];

    
    ////////////////////
    // Group Definition
    
    NSCollectionLayoutSize *groupSize = [NSCollectionLayoutSize sizeWithWidthDimension:[NSCollectionLayoutDimension fractionalWidthDimension:1.0]
                                                                       heightDimension:[NSCollectionLayoutDimension estimatedDimension:iHH]];
    NSCollectionLayoutGroup *group = [NSCollectionLayoutGroup horizontalGroupWithLayoutSize:groupSize subitems:@[item]];

    group.interItemSpacing = [NSCollectionLayoutSpacing fixedSpacing:4.0];

    
    ////////////////////
    // Section Definition
    
    NSCollectionLayoutSection *section = [NSCollectionLayoutSection sectionWithGroup:group];
    NSCollectionLayoutSize *headerSize = [NSCollectionLayoutSize sizeWithWidthDimension:[NSCollectionLayoutDimension fractionalWidthDimension:1.0]
                                                                        heightDimension:[NSCollectionLayoutDimension absoluteDimension:22]];
    NSCollectionLayoutBoundarySupplementaryItem *sectionHeader = [NSCollectionLayoutBoundarySupplementaryItem
                                                                  boundarySupplementaryItemWithLayoutSize:headerSize
                                                                  elementKind:sectionHeaderElementKind
                                                                  alignment:NSRectAlignmentTop];
    section.boundarySupplementaryItems = @[sectionHeader];
    section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsetsMake(2, 0, 4, 10);
    section.interGroupSpacing = 4.0;


    ////////////////////
    // Prepare Layout
    
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout = [[NSCollectionViewCompositionalLayout alloc]initWithSection:section];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create `NSCollectionViewDiffableDataSource+Private.h` (`.m` file is not required)

```objectivec
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface NSCollectionViewDiffableDataSource (Private)
- (void)applySnapshot:(NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot *)snapshot animatingDifferences:(BOOL)animatingDifferences completion:(void(^ _Nullable)(void))completion;
@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

2. on your `applySnapshot:animatingDifferences:` code, replace with:

```objectivec
#import "NSCollectionViewDiffableDataSource+Private.h"

[self.dataSource applySnapshot:snapshot animatingDifferences:NO completion:^{
    [self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
}];
```

If you want to avoid using Private method, observe `NSCollectionView`'s frame using `NSViewFrameDidChangeNotification` and call `- [NSCollectionViewLayout invalidateLayout]`.